# Mongo db, how to give object _id another collection's document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, collections, reference, schema

I have 2 collections called User and Location. In User, there is a location _id and this is an `Object`. Id also references the location collection. My question is what did I do wrong? When I call getUser function I want to see user information and the user's location information. What I need to do ?

**User Schema**

```
    module.exports = (function userSchema() {
    var Mongoose = require('mongoose');

    var userSchema = Mongoose.Schema({
        name: {
            type: String,
            require: true
        },
        surname: {
            type: String,
            require: true
        },
        tel: {
            type: String,
            require: true
        },
        age: {
            type: String,
            require: true
        },
        mevki_id: {
            type: String,
            require: true
        },
        location_id: [{
            type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'locations'
        }]
    });

    var collectionName = 'users';

    var User = Mongoose.model(collectionName, userSchema);

    return User;
})();
```

**User Controller**

```
    function userController() {
    var User = require('../models/UserSchema');

    this.createUser = function (req, res, next) {
        var name = req.body.name;
        var surname = req.body.surname;
        var tel = req.body.tel;
        var age = req.body.age;
        var mevki_id = req.body.mevki_id;
        var lok_id = req.body.lok_id;

        User.create({
            name: name,
            surname: surname,
            tel: tel,
            age: age,
            mevki_id: mevki_id,
            lok_id: lok_id
        }, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.send({
                    'error': err
                });
            } else {
                return res.send({
                    'result': result,
                    'status': 'successfully saved'
                });
            }
        });
    };

    this.getUser = function (req, res, next) {
        User.find()
            .populate('lok_id')
            .exec(function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return res.send({
                        'error': err
                    });
                } else {
                    return res.send({
                        'USERS': result
                    });
                }
            });
    };
    return this;
};

module.exports = new UserController();
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your `schema` is wrong:

```
var userSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
  // ...
  location_id: { type: [Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: 'locations' }
})
```

Second, in your `schema` the last field name is `location_id` while in your controller, you change it to `lok_id`.

So, fix this:

```
User.create({
  // ...
  location_id: lok_id
}
```

and this:

```
User
  .find()
  .populate('location_id')
```

**UPDATE**
In your `json` the last field name is `location_id`, therefore, fix this too:

```
this.createUser = function (req, res, next) {
  // ...
  var lok_id = req.body.location_id;
}
```

Comment: I really thnk u for your help but it deosn't work actually I can not create user. Is there any porblem my json file :

Comment: Can you please check my updated answer? And if it still does not work, can you kindly show the result of `console.log(req.body)`?

Comment: { "name": "Akif",
 "surname": "Demirezen",
 "tel": "6056056",
 "age": "35",
 "mevki_id":"2",
 
    "location_id": {
  "il":"istanbul",
  "ilce":"beylikduzu"
 }
 }
 


I post json file like above but  result is this :

{
  "result": {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "5859f736cc66d64394141b2e",
 
   "location_id": []
  },
  "status": "successfully saved"
}

Comment: the `location_id` should be a string array of ObjectId, not an object. For example, `"location_id": ["5859f736cc66d64394141b2a", "5859f736cc66d64394141b2b", "5859f736cc66d64394141b2c"]`.

Comment: yeah but mongoose have to generate this object id  into location id. Right? I think my createUser function is wrong . also I need to create Location into the create user function.

Comment: No, you have to create a `location` first, then get that id and put it into the `ObjectId` array.

Comment: I think it could be like you said, Il try thnks for help :)